# How to create glClipPlanes matching the current projection matrix?

Tags: c++, opengl, clipping, clip, projection-matrix

I'm rendering a collection of points in space which the user has manually rotated, panned, zoomed, and finally drawn a selection rectangle over a desired section. When they do this I call `gluPickMatrix` and then `gluPerspective` to construct the projection matrix, before using the `GL_SELECT` render mode to find the points in their selected area.

I want to only show the points in the selected area. For testing each point has a boolean `isSelected`, and I know selection works because the correct ones are getting selected. There are too many points for this to be feasible, though, so I'd like to use `glClipPlane` to construct four planes corresponding to the rectangular prism (*edit: I mean the frustum*) defined by the user's selection rectangle. How can I derive the coefficients to pass to `glClipPlane` after setting up the projection matrix?

Right now I'm doing this, but it ends up clipping all the points:

```
// Set up projection matrix
int viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, viewport);
gluPickMatrix(x, y, w, h, viewport);
gluPerspective(FOV_Y, ASPECT_RATIO, NEAR_PLANE, FAR_PLANE);

// Derive clip planes - this doesn't work
// Based on the paper "Fast Extraction of Viewing Frustum Planes from the World-View-Projection Matrix"
// http://graphics.cs.ucf.edu/cap4720/fall2008/plane_extraction.pdf
double t[4], r[4], b[4], l[4];
double m[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, m);
t[0] = m[3] - m[1]; t[1] = m[7] - m[5]; t[2] = m[11] - m[9]; t[3] = m[15] - m[13];
r[0] = m[3] - m[0]; r[1] = m[7] - m[4]; r[2] = m[11] - m[8]; r[3] = m[15] - m[12];
b[0] = m[3] + m[1]; b[1] = m[7] + m[5]; b[2] = m[11] + m[9]; b[3] = m[15] + m[13];
l[0] = m[3] + m[0]; l[1] = m[7] + m[4]; l[2] = m[11] + m[8]; l[3] = m[15] + m[12];

// ... Render points in GL_SELECT mode, then go back to GL_RENDER mode ...

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
// ... Apply user's pan/rotate/zoom choices here ...
// Apply clip planes
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, t);
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE1);
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE1, r);
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE2);
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE2, b);
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE3);
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE3, l);
```

I also tried normalizing and/or negating the plane coordinates, which still seems to end up clipping all the points.

Comment: When using a perspective matrix, a screen-space rectangle does not translate into a "rectangular prism". It translates into a distorted frustum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading that paper more carefully, I found the problem. I wasn't taking the model view matrix into account.

This:

```
double m[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, m);
// ... derive t, r, b, and l from m
```

Should be this:

```
double vm[16], pm[16], m[16];
glGetDoublev(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, vm);
glGetDoublev(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, pm);
matrix_mul(vm, pm, m); // m = vm * pm
// ... derive t, r, b, and l from m
```